# Matching nested array of nested subdocuments in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I am trying to create a query, that matches two criteria. Match a specific userId and match a range of Id's.

An example document could look like this:
[image: example document]

I have tried with using `find` by adding the `userId` and then using the MongoDB `$in` operator to match a list of `feature` (as an id)

```
  const featureIds = features.map(feature => feature._id)
    console.log(featureIds)
    const isFeatureExists = await this.userShopModel.find({
      userId,
      'items.feature': { $in: featureIds },
    })
    console.log(isFeatureExists)
```

I have also tried with different versions of `aggregate` but without any luck.

Any mongo experts, who can help me?

Comment: there is no `userId` field in your screenshot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use _id for filter

```
const featureIds = features.map(feature => feature._id)
    console.log(featureIds)
    const isFeatureExists = await this.userShopModel.find({
      _id : userId,
      'items.feature': { $in: featureIds },
    })
    console.log(isFeatureExists)
```